# Does gmapping require amcl?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Intiuitively, I would have thought that while a map is being built with slam, that some localization would also be happening to ensure that as the map is extended this is based on the best estimate of the current loclation (and because of the L in SLAM). I ask because I was surprised to note that in the standar .launch files for creating slam maps (e.g. gmapping) amcl is not started. I started wondering: Is that some kind of mistake, doesn't gmapping require amcl?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404657/does-gmapping-require-amcl?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2022-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

amcl is used for localisation only when your map server is publishing a static map. The gmapping algorithm does localisation as well as mapping simultaneously.

---

Originally posted by [Alex-SSoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/86099/alex-ssom/) with karma: 163 on 2022-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1